# Influence of amount element range indexes on memory consumption

Tags: marklogic

I am interested, how amount element range indexes influence on system performance? I mean those indexes which are used very rarely. Maybe I should remove they, or they do not affect on RAM memory consumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All range indexes are memory-mapped. The OS may be able to page them out if they are not being used, but either way they should not affect performance as long as there is sufficient memory space available.

You can see exactly how much memory your forests use on the forest-status page, in the admin UI. Or you can call `xdmp:forest-status()` to get the same information. It is less easy to find out how much space any given index uses, but sometimes possible.

Comment: And if some indexes uses very rarely and memory is not enough, it is better way  remove them?

Comment: @andrew-orlov It is a trade-off between how important a quick response for the rare cases is, how quick for other cases, how much space you actually have, and for instance how many tasks you are running in parallel. Indexes take a more or less fixed amount of space. Anything left is used for processing request. If you have only little spare due to lots of indexes, that you cannot run many tasks in parallel. CPF and Information Studio use parellel processing heavily.